# Addings 'rails-api' in Gemfile invalidates all existing forms with ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my existing Rails app, I decided to add API functionality. So, I added 'rails-api' gem to Gemfile. But after adding this, I am not able to submit any of my existing forms. It results in `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error. When I comment out 'rails-api' in the Gemfile, all the forms work again.

Most of my code are pretty standard:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    helper :all
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

appplication.haml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
%html
  %head
    %title= yield(:title)   
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    = yield
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rails-api` gem was built for [api-only applications](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/48c05567e9ef0cc87b12833392ce673b073e6f9f/README.md#using-rails-for-api-only-apps) and requires you to [disable authenticity](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/48c05567e9ef0cc87b12833392ce673b073e6f9f/README.md#for-already-existing-apps) checks.

There may be way around it but I suggest to split up the application or building the api without the gem.

Comment: Most of the application code like models will be common between the web app amd the api app. What is the commom workaround for this?